# Is there a way to return elements of an API call invisible to the caller?

Tags: java, sql, api, security

this is more a theoretical question and I hope this is the right place.
My intention is to write an API (or equal), someone can interact with to get a list of E-Mail adresses, which he wants to send a message to, without him seeing the Email in plain text (or being able to save it).

The other way around should work fine: someone sends a message and I send it to every E-Mail adress (E-Mail adresses invisible to caller), but the workload would be on my side.

Is this possible ?

Comment: it can only be invisible to them if the actual email adress is never in their memory. Like a REST interface running on your server.

Comment: but this means, that the messaged get's send over my server and not over the server of the actual sender of the message ?

Comment: Yes. If the client has to send the email, he needs the email adress. You can hide it as much as you want, but it can be accessed using reflection, debugging etc